# Can't access extra methods of trait implementation

Tags: scala

Please take a look at the following example:

```
trait MyTrait {
  def myTraitMeth : String
}

object TraitImplementation extends MyTrait {
  def myTraitMeth = "Works fine"
  def myExtraMeth = "Doesn't work"
}
case object Manager {
  def returnImplementation : MyTrait = TraitImplementation
}

println(Manager.returnImplementation.myExtraMeth)
```

In this scenario, what is happening is that I can't access the extra method of the trait implementation, `TraitImplementation`, because I defined the return method of the method `returnImplementation` to be of the type `MyTrait` - I cannot change this condition.

An obvious solution would be enforcing this extra method on the trait, but that is not an option for me, given the fact that other implementations of the `MyTrait` cannot have such a method.

What I really need is to make sure that the method `returnImplementation` will return something that is an implementation of `MyTrait`, and, at the same time, allow the caller of that method to use all methods that have been implemented, not only those enforced on the trait.

I tried messing around with types, going with something like

```
case object Manager {
  def returnImplementation [A <: MyTrait] : A = TraitImplementation
}
```

but this leads to a type mismatch, because the compiler cannot understand that A is a generic type.

Any ideas on how to accomplish it?

Comment: Why not just: `def returnImplementation : MyTraitImplementation.type = TraitImplementation` ? - If you need the users of you method to see an apple and you are going to return an apple then mark the return type of the method as an apple not as fruit.

Comment: That would do it, but I want to keep that part of the code fixed, due to project demands. That Implementation will change overtime - also, I'm trying to write a test that will be agnostic regarding the implementation. So, that is not a viable option for me, because it would depend on a specific implementation.

Comment: So you want to be agnostic to the implementation but then also want to use something specific to the implementation? You have a paradox. -  What about something like: `trait MyExtTrait extends MyTrait { def myExtraMeth: String }` Then `object TraitImplementation extends MyExtTrait { ... }` And then: `def returnImplementation : MyExtTrait = TraitImplementation` That way you are still agnostic to the implementation but have the extended capabilities explicit on the interface.

Comment: I didn't get what exactly would be specific to the implementation - what I want is to enforce the implementation will extend MyTrait. 

I'm not going to lie, I don't quite like the idea of having the burden of an extra trait with with the single purpose of fulfilling a seemingly simple constraint like that. I was hoping to achieve it with some type restriction, or something along those lines. That said, though, what you proposed is a valid, working solution, so I ask you to post it as an answer. If nothing simpler comes, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: **Scala** is a strongly & statically typed language, so the compiler has to verify the correctness of your program. Yes, you may say that a method returns any subtype of a **trait** but due _Liskov_ that is exactly the same as saying that you are going to return the trait. Unless the method is able to return different subtypes but then you would need a way to statically prove which subtype is the one that will be returned for each call.

Comment: Also, that would mean that on this line `Manager.returnImplementation.myExtraMeth` we would already know that the returned value is of type `MyTraitImplementation.type` thus leaking all the implementation details. So you would just make your code more complex, without any advantage. So you would still require to create another trait to hide the real implementation and just expose the subtype. - I believe there is another alternative, using a refined type with **structural typing** but that would not reduce too much the boiler plate and would introduce the use of reflection, which is very slow.

Comment: Funny you mentioned it... We have this implemented, but using reflection. I look at my colleague's code and thought to myself "Damn, way too complex. There must be an easier way of doing that". It seems to me that I was wrong - at least, in that scenario, he was able to hide that reflection part, leaving it restricted to the tests, without contaminating the main code with it. I'm sad, but more enlightened, I think...

Comment: The killer thing here for me is the Liskov principle you mentioned - I was not aware of that behavior in Scala for the traits.

Comment: I would argue that you never ever need **reflection** in Scala _(of course there are valid use cases, but I consider them to be extremely rare and very complex to justify its use)_. **Scala** as a language is very expressive and with the help of tools like **Shapeless** or **macros**, runtime reflection is barely really needed. - I would encourage you to either edit this question or open a new one sharing your complete problem, probably there is a safer approach. - BTW, that is not just **Scala** any language that has subtyping should _(must)_ respect the Liskov principle.

Comment: Gonna look into those things - being new to Scala (1 month or so), I'm still completely unaware of them. About the question, I'm gonna think what exactly to do in order to be more helpful to future readers. Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you are new to Scala please keep away of **Shapeless**, **macros** and even more **reflection**. You will just shoot yourself on the foot.

Comment: No, `def returnImplementation [A <: MyTrait] : A = TraitImplementation` doesn't work because it says "you can ask for any type `A` which is a subtype of `MyTrait` and I will return an `A`". These subtypes include `Nothing`, `Trait with Iterable[Int]`, etc. etc. and `TraitImplementation` doesn't satisfy all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I originally wanted to leave this as a comment, but there was a discussion going on so that the space was getting kind of crowded. I decided to write it up as an answer instead.

This problem you have sounds like something you would get around by using case matching. When returnImplementation returns a trait of type MyTrait, case match on it to get the desired subclass, and depending on which subclass it is, have different behavior. Wrap it in an Option if you want monadic fail-fast behavior, so that only certain subclass will trigger the creation of some result. The result will be Some(...) if the desired subclass with the desired method was found, None otherwise.

```
trait MyTrait {
  def myTraitMeth : String
}

object TraitImplementation extends MyTrait {
  def myTraitMeth = "Works fine"
  def myExtraMeth = "Doesn't work"
}
case object Manager {
  def returnImplementation : MyTrait = TraitImplementation
}
```

For your println statement, you would call it like so:

```
Manager.returnImplementation match {
  case TraitImplementation => println(TraitImplementation.myExtraMeth)
  case _ =>
}
```

If you want to keep your code purely functional with no side-effects like println functions, do the following:

```
val result = Manager.returnImplementation match {
  case TraitImplementation => Some(TraitImplementation)
  case _ => None
}
```

`result` will be of type Option[TraitImplementation] and you can pass it around for context dependent behavior.

If you have side effecting code, like your println statement, you can isolate it from the rest of your purely function code by calling foreach on this Option like so:

```
result.foreach(x => println(x.myExtraMeth))
```

Based on the discussion Luis and you had, you can also case match on MyExtTrait for the desired behavior.

```
trait MyExtTrait {
  def myExtraMeth: String
}

val result = Manager.returnImplementation match {
  case x: MyExtTrait => println(x.myExtraMeth)
  case _ => 
}
```

or

```
val result = Manager.returnImplementation match {
  case x: MyExtTrait => Some(x)
  case _ =>  None
}

result.foreach(x => println(x.myExtraMeth))
```

Comment: I would argue that would only make everything mor complex and still would leak the implementation type, thus not winning anything. Also, the moment you have to do a runtime check on an instance of an interface to know which subclass _(not subtype)_ you have, in order to execute different code, you have a failed abstraction, which is a code smell.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I wasn't aware of the distinction between subtypes and subclasses, so I have changed my answer based on your correction.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I am currently working on a project at work that, based on what you have said, overuses case matching in precisely the way I have described here. Thank you for your comment. I will think carefully about how to clean up my implementation. (That is, for my work project. My answer I will leave unchanged as is, since I cannot imagine how I can answer the OP's question while taking into account the comments you have made.)

Comment: For anyone interested in the difference between subtyping and subclassing, please check [this](https://typelevel.org/blog/2017/02/13/more-types-than-classes.html) Also keep in mind that **variance** _(e.g. `List[+A]` List is covariant on A)_ is a concept of **types** not **classes**.

Comment: PS: Take into a account that **pattern matching** itself is not wrong. But type pattern matching is the one that one must try to avoid. For example, **pattern matching** on an `Option` to check if it is a `Some` or a `None` is perfectly fine _(some may argue that you should prefer HOF like `map`, but still)_. But if you have a trait that represent a repository and you use pattern matching to check it it is the posgress one or the in-memory one, that would mean that your abstraction _(the trait)_ was bad designed or bad used.